# PostqreSQL Duplicate Values WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, not-exists

I made this code:

```
INSERT into author(authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
select '".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname1'])."','".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname1'])."','".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname2'])."','".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname2'])."'
from author
where not exists(select authorfirstname1, authorlastname1, authorfirstname2, authorlastname2 from author
where author.authorfirstname1='".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname1'])."'
and author.authorlastname1='".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname1'])."'
and author.authorfirstname2='".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname2'])."'
and author.authorlastname2='".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname2'])."'
);
```

The point of this code should be that it checks, if a value allready exists in database and if it doesnt, then it enters it.
This '".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname2'])."' represents an input, but could easyly be replaced with '%myentereddata%'

My problem is that it doesnt do anything...doesnt even give error message, its success, but it doesnt enter data if data doesnt exist in db allready and not sure if it stops entering data if data exists.

So I would be thankful if someone could help me to solve the problem with this code or give another example how to do it differently, so that it would work.

My id is primary and serial, so no need to insert it

```
INSERT INTO author (authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
VALUES ('one','two','three','four');
```

Query returned successfully: 1 row affected, 60 ms execution time.

```
INSERT into author(authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
select 'one','two','three','four'
from author
where not exists(select authorfirstname1, authorlastname1, authorfirstname2, authorlastname2 from author
where author.authorfirstname1='one'
and author.authorlastname1='two'
and author.authorfirstname2='three'
and author.authorlastname2='four'
);
```

Query returned successfully: 657 rows affected, 40 ms execution time.

```
INSERT into author(authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
select 'new','new','new','new'
from author
where not exists(select authorfirstname1, authorlastname1, authorfirstname2, authorlastname2 from author
where author.authorfirstname1='new'
and author.authorlastname1='new'
and author.authorfirstname2='new'
and author.authorlastname2='new'
);
```

Query returned successfully: 1314 rows affected, 70 ms execution time.

Comment: do you WANT to get an error if you try to insert a row that is already there? Or do you want to insert it if it is not there, and quietly ignore it if it is already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are two FROM clauses instead of one. You are in effect inserting the same row as many times as there are rows in the entire table (when the WHERE clause is satisfied).
The query should be (note that the first FROM has been removed compared to your version):

```
INSERT into author(authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
select 'one','two','three','four'
where not exists(select 1 from author
where author.authorfirstname1='one'
and author.authorlastname1='two'
and author.authorfirstname2='three'
and author.authorlastname2='four'
);
```

The columns in the inner select have also been removed. `SELECT 1 FROM...` is good enough to check if a row exists, there's no need to extract specific columns, they're going to be discarded  on the upper level anyway.

Another unrelated problem is that the escaping done with `addslashes` will produce an invalid query as soon as any injected parameter contain a quote character.

This is because when PG's `standard_conforming_strings` is set to ON, the backslash is a normal character that doesn't escape anything. Since PostgreSQL 9.1, it's ON by default.

Use `pg_escape_string` instead.

Comment: @mudsao Please mark this answer as correct then (the hook below the numbers on the left)

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to get sure that there are no duplicate entries in the table, you should use `UNIQUE`.

That way whenever you `INSERT` a line that is already there, you will get an error.

Like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON author (authorfirstname1, authorlastname1, authorfirstname2, authorlastname2);
```

Afterwards you will not be able to `INSERT` the same set of firstnames and lastnames twice.

You then `INSERT` like this:

```
INSERT into author(authorfirstname1, authorlastname1,authorfirstname2, authorlastname2)
VALUES ('".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname1'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname1'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['authorfirstname2'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['authorlastname2'])."')
```

Comment: This is what I got when using values that were'nt in database:
Query returned successfully: 606208 rows affected, 18829 ms execution time.
(didnt eneter anything)
And this is what i got using it again with same values:
Query returned successfully: 1212416 rows affected, 41933 ms execution time.
(still no entry made...)
Mayby its my postgresql problem, using PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: did you commit your transaction?

Comment: @mudsao Was it your intention to INSERT 600.000 new Lines? Or do you just want to insert one line?

Comment: @mudsao It is not a bug. Your code works as it should, but it I doubt that it does what you want. So please answer to my other comments.

Comment: @Angelo: run your last query several times and you'll see that each time it does not insert one row but the number of rows of the table.

Comment: @DanielVérité I know. (I even describe it in the answer)

Comment: @Angelo: so this duplication of rows was the problem in the sense that it was not what the asker intended in the first place.

Comment: @DanielVérité Yeah, that wasn't clear at first, but you are right. I removed the second part of the answer.